# which directory should i use for Lucene Index directory?

Tags: java, postgresql, indexing, lucene

I am new to Lucene and I wonder, which directory is the best solution for indexing.

My project is a Java-based web project which uses PostgreSQL for database. Searching is the most important part of the project. Therefore, I decided to use Lucene, but I couldn't decide directory for indexing.

When I searching Lucene I found [this article](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2008/06/creating-search-index-in-database.html) which says local file system is not good, and it offers JDBCDirectory.

Which directory should I use?

- local file directory
- jdbcdirectory (but i'm planning to use PostgreSQL and I don't know how it will be.)
- ramdirectory (I think this cannot be because of the too much data)
- and your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article that you are referencing is specifically about clustered environments. I currently work on an enterprise web-app and I use the FS (file system) directory provider and it works great. If you do not have a "complicated" environment then I would recommend using it.

The RAM directory provider is not a viable option for a production environment in my opinion so I wouldn't even consider that one. It is useful for testing though.